# Adding code via addEventListener on ID's taken by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Yesterday, I've asked the same, but today I will try to be little more specific, with working example.

I want to add some code by `addEventListener`. I would use `DOMContentLoaded`, but ID which I'm trying to select is not available on page load. It's taken by AJAX GET method. I could use `mouseover`, but it iterate the code on any move. I could also use `click` event, but I don't want it to show on click, but just when it's shown. How can I handle it?

I can't attach it to you easily in here, because the domain of file would be another, but my added part of code is:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  document.querySelector("h1").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div>asd</div>');
});
```

That works with these events like `click` or `mousover`, but I want it just on load.

You can test the whole code here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_first
With my added code it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.w3schools.com/js/ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  document.querySelector("h1").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div>asd</div>');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you set your logic from ajax callback???

Comment: I don't have any access to ajax script, because it's a part of third-party shop engine. Here is just an example of the behaviour. I can only inject code by another script

Comment: Ok so you could use mutation observer or even set a fake CSS animation to this specific element and bind animationstart event

Comment: Andy - no. I can only add JS or CSS overwrite. @a-wolff could you show me how should I use it on this example? I've tried mutation observer, but I'm not sure how final code should look like :(

Comment: Doesn't the 3rd party API have a callback function? Else how do you control what happens to the data the 3rd party API gives you?

Comment: It's just one of those ready-to-use shop engines, without any access to the core code. I can only add JS code by the admin cockpit.